# getbalance says 0 for incoming TX even though 0-conf is allowed

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, json-rpc, balance, replace-by-fee

```
> $bitcoin_rpc.getnewaddress("myaddress", "bech32")
 => "bc1q9kvfyjxtk9tvkzgpkf4x8zs42sddwlyanz3z6z" 
> $bitcoin_rpc.getbalance
 => 0.0 
> $bitcoin_rpc.getbalance("*", 0)
 => 0.0 
> $bitcoin_rpc.listtransactions
 => [{"address"=>"bc1q9kvfyjxtk9tvkzgpkf4x8zs42sddwlyanz3z6z", "category"=>"receive", "amount"=>0.00025, "label"=>"myaddress", "vout"=>1, "confirmations"=>0, "trusted"=>false, "txid"=>"ad922349668c17c3ab47081f6dbc6e7e8f68473840146bfdd18f35f7d0bca216", "walletconflicts"=>[], "time"=>1574217056, "timereceived"=>1574217056, "bip125-replaceable"=>"yes"}] 
> Time.now.to_i
 => 1574217344
```

What's the magic behind it? Since `confirmation=0` is default, I would expect a return value of 0.00025.

Comment: I suspect it's because the fee paid by that transaction is so low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getbalance` returns the balance that your node currently considers spendable. According to your console output, the transaction that sent you the output was flagged as `"bip125-replaceable"=>"yes"`. Since a transaction flagged as replaceable can be amended or retracted by the sender until it gets confirmed, an output from such a transaction will not be considered reliable and not used as an input until confirmed.